# increase the speed of a chess bot

Tags: javascript, performance, chess

I am making a chess bot that uses the minimax algorithm. I am also using the chess.js library. It currently runs very slowly, even at a very low depth. How can I make my algorithm run faster? Any help would be appreciated!

here is the algorithm

```
class MiniMaxBot
{
constructor(chessGame,player_color)
{
this.chess = chessGame;
this.color = player_color == "w"? 'b': 'w';
this.depthLimit = 3;
}



move()
{ let maxIndex = 0;
  let maxScore = -Infinity;
  let moves = this.chess.moves();
  let fen = this.chess.fen();
  for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
  { 
    let chess = new Chess();
    chess.load(fen);
    chess.move(moves[i]);
    let score = this.minimax(chess.fen(),this.depthLimit,-Infinity, Infinity, true);
    if(maxScore < score )
    {
      maxScore = score;
      maxIndex = i;
    }
    //console.log(score);

  }
    return moves[maxIndex];
}

minimax(fen,depth, alpha, beta, max)
{
  let chess  = new Chess();
  chess.load(fen);
 
if(depth <= 0 || this.leafNode(fen) == true)
{
  let value = this.evaluation(fen);
  
  return value;
}


if (max == true)
{
  let moves = chess.moves();
  let bestValue = -Infinity;
  for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
  {  chess.load(fen);
    chess.move(moves[i]);
    let value = this.minimax(chess.fen(),depth-1, alpha, beta, false);
    bestValue =  Math.max(value,bestValue);

    alpha = Math.max(alpha, bestValue);
    if(beta <= alpha)
     break;
  }
  return bestValue;
  
} 
else if( max == false)
{
  let moves = chess.moves();
  let bestValue = Infinity;
  for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
  {
    chess.load(fen);
    chess.move(moves[i]);
    let value = this.minimax(chess.fen(),depth-1, alpha, beta, true);
    bestValue = Math.min(value,bestValue);
    beta = Math.min(beta, bestValue);
    if(beta <= alpha)
    break;
  }
  return bestValue;

}




}




leafNode(fen)
{
let chess = new Chess();
 chess.load(fen);

 if(chess.in_checkmate() || chess.in_stalemate() || chess.in_threefold_repetition() )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  
}

evaluation(fen) {
 let pieceValues = this.pieceValues();
  let score = 0;
  const boardState = fen.split(' ')[0];
  const rows = boardState.split('/');
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let columnIndex = 0;
    const row = rows[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
      const currentChar = row[j];
      if (currentChar in pieceValues) {
        score += pieceValues[currentChar];
      } else {
        columnIndex += parseInt(currentChar);
      }
    }
  }
  return score;
}

pieceValues()
{let black = {
  'p': -10,
  'n': -30,
  'b': -30,
  'r': -50,
  'q': -90,
  'P': 10,
  'N': 30,
  'B': 30,
  'R': 50,
  'Q': 90
};

let white = {
  'p': -10,
  'n': -30,
  'b': -30,
  'r': -50,
  'q': -90,
  'P': 10,
  'N': 30,
  'B': 30,
  'R': 50,
  'Q': 90
};
return this.color == 'b' ? black:white;
}

}
```

here is my github repository
https://github.com/jakmo3000/chessAI/tree/main/chess

Comment: Don't create a new chess instance -- keep working with one instance. Don't use `load(fen)` -- eliminate any use of `fen` (except maybe in the driver code). Instead take back the last move when backtracking.